# read SharePoint list field titles

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have created visual web part in visual studio 2013. I want to read

1. list field title
2. list data

I am reading first list field title correct rest are random numbers, I am not sure where I am doing mistake

### My list

[image]

### My C# class

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
        {
          using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb())
          {
              SPList _list = _web.Lists["MyUWLContent_List"];

              SPView _view = _list.DefaultView;

              //Get a collection of view field names. 
              StringCollection _viewFields = _view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();

              // Print the value of each view field. 
              foreach (string fieldName in _viewFields)
              {
                  Label1.Text += fieldName + "<BR>";         
              }
          } //end SPWeb
        } //end SPSite 
}
```

but I am getting following output from web part

[image]

Comment: As a side note, you should use `SPContext.Current.Web` instead of opening a new SPWeb object. This will avoid useles database roundtrips.

Comment: is SPContext.Current.Web will solve the issue???

Comment: nice, why someone mark me negative on this question; really what is wrong with that???????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are calling `ToStringCollection()`, but you can do something like this instead:

```
// Get your list
SPList myList = web.Lists["MyUWLContent_List"];

// Get the default view
SPView defaultView = someList.DefaultView;

// Loop through all the fields in the default view
foreach (SPField field in defaultView.ViewFields)
{
    // this gets the title of your field
    var fieldTitle = field.Title;

    Label1.Text += fieldTitle + "<BR>"; 
}
```